# R kable formatted with kableExtra::cell_spec() gives verbatim latex-commands instead of expected format

Tags: r, pdf, latex, kableextra

## Problem

- R Markdown with RStudio
- Knitting to PDF
- kable formatted with kableExtra::cell_spec() gives verbatim latex-commands instead of expected format

## Questions

- Is it reproducible in other environments?
- Any ideas for solution?

## RMD commands

````
---
title: "MWE cell_spec latex"
author: "Thomas"
date: "2022-12-16"
output: 
 pdf_document:
   keep_tex: yes

---

```{r setup, include=TRUE }


library("tidyverse")
library("kableExtra")

data <- data.frame(item=c("I'm red", "What color am I?"))

kable(data)

data %>%
  mutate(item = cell_spec(item, "latex",color = "red"))%>%
  kable()


```
````

## Tex-File in tabular-environment

The tex-file shows, that pandoc outputs \textbackslash{} for the cell specification instead of \

\begin{verbatim}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
item\
\hline
\textbackslash{}textcolor{red}{I'm red}\
\hline
\textbackslash{}textcolor{red}{What color am I?}\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{verbatim}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very nearly there. Try:

````
---
title: "MWE cell_spec latex"
author: "Thomas"
date: "2022-12-16"
output: 
 pdf_document:
   keep_tex: yes

---

    ```{r setup, results=`asis` }
    
    
    library(dplyr)
    library(kableExtra)
    
    data <- data.frame(item=c("I'm red", "What color am I?"))
    
    data  |> 
      mutate(item = cell_spec(item, "latex", color = "red")) |> 
      kable(escape = FALSE)
    
    ```
````

Comment: Peter, thanks a lot. "escape = FALSE" did the trick, results="asis" was not necessary for my environment.